# jQuery hover weirdness when on child

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/GNQyt/

Hover over green box, then move mouse to child list. Suddenly starts blinking like mad, anyway to prevent this *but maintain the hover still over child*?

**edited afterward*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your working code http://jsfiddle.net/GNQyt/18 
I used the delay method. You have 1000ms once you leave the `.icn` to reach the `ul`. If you hit the `ul` in the desired time, the request for fading it out gets removed.

```
$('.icn').on({
    mouseenter: function() {

        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));

        $(this).children('ul').show('fast');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {

        var self = this;

        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).children('ul').hide('fast');
        }, 1000);

        $(self).data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
    }
});​
```

Comment: Here is your working code -> http://jsfiddle.net/GNQyt/18/ The delay is set to 1000ms

Comment: Thank you, I believe this would be the simplest solution to my current site. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GNQyt/5/

Use mouseenter, not hover in that case

Here is a nice little interactive comparison of "Mouseenter" vs. "Mouseover" http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

The Demo makes it very clear.

Comment: This seems to hide the child completely though, I'd like it to maintain the hover state on either parent or child, and hide when mouse leaves, just preventing the flicker when I move over child.

Answer (score 1):

The flicker is resulting from moving away from the green box and to the pop-up. The distance between the to causes the computer to close the pop-up because you've moved away from the green box, but just before the pop-up is completely closed, the mouse arrives at the pop-up, causing it to open again. Ideally, the two should intersect to allow the mouse to move directly from the box to the pop-up. Or, increase the delay before closing the pop-up.

Comment: How would I increase the delay exactly? Using a "setTimeout( function() { $(this).children('ul').toggle('fast');}, 200)" seems to kill the hover completely.

Answer (score 1):

Flickering is not because of hovering the child but catching the menu when it is being closed. Moving the menu top left by `top: 0px; left: 0px;` solves it. Moreover changing height and width of the span by `height: 500px; width: 500px;` also solves. In order to be height and width to be effective change the span to div.

Comment: Unfortunately the list is meant to be separated from the span. It's an icon that has a pop-up dialog to the side, but it's possible for one of the pop ups to also have a link, hence why I need to maintain the hover.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GNQyt/17/

Here's another solution with a hitbox. This one is pretty much hacked, but i think you will get a sense out of it :)

Please keep in mind that

```
<span>
    <div>
    </div>
</span>
```

is an illegal operation, since you shouldnt wrap block elements into inline elements.